# filter information gets lost when visual studio solution is downloaded from subversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, svn

I am uploading my visual studio solution to subversion. in my visual studion solution I have filters under which I have kept different files of the project so that it is easier for me to manage. after upload to subversion, I download the files to a different machine. when I open up the solution in the diffeerent machine I observe the the filtering information is gone and it gets kind of unmanagable.

My question is what file/files am I possible not uploading to subversion which contains the filtering information?

Comment: hmm... have you tried to store .suo file under SVN? The solution user options (.suo) file contains user specific settings such as location of the breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2012 I check in to SVN only the `.sln` file, the `.vcxproj` file, and the `.filters` file (assuming one project in the solution).  I can check it out on any machine and it loads fine.

Answer (score 1):

You normally get an `suo` file next to your solution. This file contains your personal preferences, such as what you have expanded and collapsed and so on.

You wouldn't normally check this in as different users could have different preferences - but it is possible that the behaviour you are expecting is in this file.

You could test copying that file to see if I am correct - but I don't recommend you check it in as each user would keep overwriting all other users' preferences.